# Redo "git merge" with no fast forward option?

Tags: git

I did

```
> git checkout b1
> git merge b2
> git push
```

and I got a fast-forwarded branch `b1`, which I didn't want.
Is there a way to revert and do a merge without fast-forward (`merge --no-ff`) instead?

Comment: Yes, just reset hard back to before the merge. Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to find out what the old commit was if you don't know it.  Then

```
$ git reset --hard <OLD_B1_COMMMIT>
$ git merge --no-ff b2
```